# R, Shiny, plotting a reactive data frame (data goes "missing")

Tags: r, shiny

Given the following ui.R and server.R and circuit.csv; I can produce a simple plot which reacts to the user input (power in this case).

However, not all values for power are returned.  For example, .5 produces a plot whereas .6 does not, so on and so forth at random occurrence throughout the power range.

If i plot as a table instead, to check my work, same thing, certain power inputs work as expected and others produce no table, and also no plot when asking to plot.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


shinyUI(fluidPage(
hr(),
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
sliderInput("power",label = "Power",
            min = 0, max = 5, value = .5, step = .1)

),
  mainPanel(
   p("Lum vs Distance by Power"),
   plotOutput('plot1')
  )
)
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.table(file = "circuit.csv", sep=",", header = TRUE)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    df2 <- subset(df,df$pow==input$power)

    p <- ggplot(df2)+
    geom_point(aes(x=dist, y=lum))
    print(p)

  })

})
```

[Link to github](https://github.com/BobbyChew/Lum-vs-Dist-by-Pow-R-Shiny) (for csv data)

I would post images but am not allowed to do so at this time.

Comment: Are you sure you have data for every level of power?

Comment: @BobChew I am getting the same behavior you describe. The source of the problem seems to be with input$power. When I replace `sliderInput` with `numericInput`, it works.

Comment: Not related to your question: it's common to use `subset(df, pow == input$power)` instead of `subset(df, df$pow == input$power)`

Comment: This appears to be a bug with `sliderInput` given that the filter is so sporadic.  Strangely, it finds 0.6 if using `<=` but obviously not what you want.  You may want to submit to [shiny issues](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues)

Comment: Interesting finds guys, thank you very much for your time.  I will test and update.